# TCP Server listening in the background without blocking other operations

Tags: go, tcp, goroutine

I'm writing a TCP Server and Client in Go, just as a working example to get familiar with this language. I want to write a server, let's call it MyServer, which does the following - it has a backend TCP Server, which listens for incoming messages, but it also has a Client which allows him to send other messages, independently on the received once. However, I don't know how to tell MyServer to listen "in the background", without blocking the main thread. Here is the code for my TCPServer:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  startListener()
  doOtherThins()
}

func startListener() {
  listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:9998")
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
      os.Exit(1)
  }
  defer listener.Close()
  fmt.Println("Listening on " + "localhost:9998")
  for {
      // Listen for an incoming connection.
      conn, err := listener.Accept()
      if err != nil {
          fmt.Println("Error during accepting: ", err.Error())
          os.Exit(1)
      }
      go handleConnection(conn)
  }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
  buf := make([]byte, 1024)

  _, err := conn.Read(buf)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
  }

  conn.Write([]byte("Message correctly received."))
  conn.Close()
}
```

Function `startListener()` blocks the main function, so the function `doOtherThins()` (which I want to independently send packets to other servers) is never triggered as long as the server is listening. I tried to change the main function and use the goroutine:

```
func main() {
  go startListener()
  doOtherThins()
}
```

But then the server is not listening for the incoming packets (it just triggers `doOtherThins()` and ends `main()`). 
Is it possible to spin the listener in the background, to allow the main thread do also other operations?

Answer (score 1):

Your last example should do what you want, the issue is that the main thread ends before you can do anything. There's 2 solutions start `doOtherThins()` on another goroutine and then call `startListener()` which blocks but the other goroutine is already running:

```
func main() {
  go doOtherThins()
  startListener()
}
```

Or use [waitGroups](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait until the code ends before exiting.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a cleaner way of achieving this using channels.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Create a channel to synchronize goroutines
    finish := make(chan bool)

    server8001 := http.NewServeMux()
    server8001.HandleFunc("/foo", foo8001)
    server8001.HandleFunc("/bar", bar8001)

    go func() {
        http.ListenAndServe(":8001", server8001)
    }()

    go func() {
        //do other things in a separate routine
        fmt.Println("doing some work")
        // you can also start a new server on a different port here
    }()

    // do other things in the main routine

    <-finish //wait for all the routines to finish
}

func foo8001(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Listening on 8001: foo "))
}

func bar8001(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Listening on 8001: bar "))
}
```

Comment: i d rather block on the listen op, instead of adding a new chan. whatever you do next, you ll need to sleep a bit before invoking the client. you should have something like Listen, check err || wait a bit, start new routine to consume client.

Answer (score -1):

adding another variation of  Anuruddha  answer

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    server8001 := http.NewServeMux()
    server8001.HandleFunc("/foo", foo8001)
    server8001.HandleFunc("/bar", bar8001)

    unblock(func() error {
        return http.ListenAndServe(":8001", server8001)
    })//forgot err check, must be done!

    res, err := http.Get("http://0.0.0.0:8001/foo")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, res.Body)
    os.Exit(0)
}

func unblock(h func() error) error {
    w := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        w <- h()
    }()
    select {
    case err := <-w:
        return err
    case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 50):
        return nil
    }
}

func foo8001(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Listening on 8001: foo "))
}

func bar8001(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Listening on 8001: bar "))
}
```